# Joomla 3.4.3 Jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, joomla

On my Joomla 3.4.3 installation, in firefox I'm using Inspect Element to debug. In the console I'm seeing an item that states: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js`
and to the right of this item it says

> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 234ms]

I've searched around and was instructed to do an override. My question is, what files do I need to override to target that specific googleapi for jquery to get rid of this item in my debug console?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The URL included is wrong. This has probably been added inside your template file incorrectly.

```
/templates/nameOfYourTemplate/index.php
```

You need to look for the URL in there and change it to:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js

Notice that your URL currently says

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/ **1.8.**
>   1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've taken a look at the index.php according to the template I have assigned which is the Protostar template and I don't see any line in there where it's calling for that googleapi jquery. Any other places I should look?

Comment: It could be a lot of places. Try "view source" in your browser and look for that url. Then update your question with the 5 lines before and after the line where it occurs.

Comment: Here's what I've done. I had jQuery Easy plugin enabled. As soon as I disabled it, and refreshed the browser with inspect element, that particular warning disappeared. So perhaps it was associated with jQuery Easy?

Comment: Not perhaps. Definitely.